# Non-linear control flow added to AS3 through a new 'goto' keyword

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, goto, asc2

I recently read from adobe about the asc2.0 and air sdk 14 that there is a GOTO keyword you can use now, yet I cannot find anything other than that in the release notes online. Does anyone have an example of how to use goto?

Comment: Keep mind too, that it's an undocumented feature

Comment: If you found it helpful,  it would be great if you accepted the answer to bring closure to this question

Answer (score 1):

The most basic of examples:

```
goto myLabel;
trace("I'm going to get skipped");

myLabel:
trace("Here we are at the end");
```

If you run this, you will only get the ending trace.

`goto` in most languages (including AS3) will move code execution to the corresponding label.

AS3 has always supported labels, but previously you would use the `break` keyword to break out of a label.

```
myLabelOuter: {
    trace("First Outer");
    myLabelInner: {
        trace("First Inner");
        break myLabelOuter;
        trace("you'll never see this");
    }

    trace("You'll never see this either");
}
```

Here is a decent article I found with a simple web search that includes a bunch of examples:  http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2584

Keep in mind, the `goto` keyword only works in the Actionscript Compiler 2 (asc2),  so it will not work in the current version of FlashPro (CC 2014), but only in FlashBuilder or other tools that use the newer compiler.